# In javascript, how can you assert that two items are equal?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, rhino, qunit

I am running Rhino and trying to determine how to do an assert_equals() or its equivalent in Javascript. From the Rhino shell I can load qunit, but I can't create an assertion that will fail.

What is the easiest way to use assertions in Javascript? I will be using Javascript in environments other than a web browser, so knowing how to do this from the Rhino shell would be very helpful.

Example of what does not work.

```
js> load("qunit.js")
js> equals(5,4,"message")
js> 
js>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly easy to implement your own `assert()` function in javascript which throws an exception when the assertion fails. The implementation [documented here](https://web.archive.org/web/20061025015342/http://aymanh.com/9-javascript-tips-you-may-not-know) is fairly concise and should do the job.

Comment: Yeah. That was an efficient approach. I just needed to create a short function called assert_equal(x,y) that returned true when equal and threw an exception when not equal. Very light weight approach. Thanks

Comment: I used this approach to create an `assert_equal(expression, result)` function.  Throwing the message `'Expression produced "' .. expression .. '" which did no tequal "' .. result .. '".'` was better for me than adding a custom message to every assert.  I couldn't find a good way to include the original expression passed to the function without using `eval()` or copy-pasting stuff.

Comment: I'm afraid that link is dead. You can find the wayback machine link [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20061025015342/http://aymanh.com/9-javascript-tips-you-may-not-know)